# I get no errors but the numbers do not add to the JTextField

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jframe

I am trying to create a program in java that basically makes a fake lottery. It allows you to either get a quick pick of 5 random numbers or it allows you to choose your own. The quick pick and personal buttons work correctly. As soon as you click quick pick it displays 5 random numbers in the 5 random boxes. Now the problem is that when the play button is clicked the winning numbers are not displayed nor does the program keep track of how many years it would take and and how many drawings and it does not display if i got 3 out of 6 numbers and so on. Keep in mind the program runs without a single error.

**Here is my code for the first class that makes the gui:**

```
public class LotteryInterface extends JFrame {

LotteryEvent hello = new LotteryEvent(this);

//set up row 1 
JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
ButtonGroup option = new ButtonGroup();
JCheckBox quickpick = new JCheckBox("Quick Pick", false);
JCheckBox personal = new JCheckBox("Personal", true);
//set up row 2 
JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
JLabel numbersLabel = new JLabel("Your Picks", JLabel.RIGHT);
JTextField[] numbers = new JTextField[6];
JLabel winnersLabel = new JLabel("Winners", JLabel.RIGHT);
JTextField[] winners = new JTextField[6];
//set up row 3
JPanel row3 = new JPanel();
JButton play = new JButton("Play");
JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
//set up row 4
JPanel row4 = new JPanel();
JLabel got3label = new JLabel("3 of 6", JLabel.RIGHT);
JTextField got3 = new JTextField("0");
JLabel got4Label = new JLabel("4 of 6", JLabel.RIGHT);
JTextField got4 = new JTextField("0");
JLabel got5label = new JLabel("5 of 6", JLabel.RIGHT);
JTextField got5 = new JTextField("0");
JLabel got6label = new JLabel("6 of 6", JLabel.RIGHT);
JTextField got6 = new JTextField("0", 10);
JLabel drawingsLabel = new JLabel("Drawings", JLabel.RIGHT);
JTextField drawings = new JTextField();
JLabel yearsLabel = new JLabel("Years", JLabel.RIGHT);
JTextField years = new JTextField();

public LotteryInterface() {
    super("Lottery Interface");
    setLookAndFeel();
    setSize(550, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10);
    setLayout(layout);

    personal.addItemListener(hello);
    quickpick.addItemListener(hello);
    play.addActionListener(hello);
    stop.addActionListener(hello);
    reset.addActionListener(hello);

    FlowLayout layout1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10);
    option.add(quickpick);
    option.add(personal);
    row1.setLayout(layout1);
    row1.add(quickpick);
    row1.add(personal);
    add(row1);

    GridLayout layout2 = new GridLayout(2, 7, 10, 10);
    row2.setLayout(layout2);
    row2.add(numbersLabel);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        numbers[i] = new JTextField();
        row2.add(numbers[i]);
    }
    row2.add(winnersLabel);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        winners[i] = new JTextField();
        winners[i].setEditable(false);
        row2.add(winners[i]);
    }
    add(row2);

    FlowLayout layout3 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10);
    row3.setLayout(layout3);
    row3.add(stop);
    row3.add(play);
    row3.add(reset);
    add(row3);

    GridLayout layout4 = new GridLayout(2, 3, 20, 10);
    row4.setLayout(layout4);
    row4.add(got3label);
    got3.setEditable(false);
    row4.add(got3);
    row4.add(got4Label);
    got4.setEditable(false);
    row4.add(got4);
    row4.add(got5label);
    got5.setEditable(false);
    row4.add(got5);
    row4.add(got6label);
    got6.setEditable(false);
    row4.add(got6);
    row4.add(drawingsLabel);
    drawings.setEditable(false);
    row4.add(drawings);
    row4.add(yearsLabel);
    years.setEditable(false);
    row4.add(years);
    add(row4);


    setVisible(true);

}

private void setLookAndFeel() {


}

public static void main(String args[]) {


    LotteryInterface yeah = new LotteryInterface();

    }

}
```

**and here is the second class that makes the gui do things:**

```
public class LotteryEvent extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener, Runnable {

LotteryInterface gui;
Thread playing;


public LotteryEvent(LotteryInterface in ) {
    gui = in ;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String command = event.getActionCommand();
    if (command.equals("Play")) {
        startPlaying();
    }
    if (command.equals("Stop")) {
        stopPlaying();
    }
    if (command.equals("Reset")) {
        clearAllFields();
    }

}

void startPlaying() {
    playing = new Thread(this);
    playing.start();
    gui.play.setEnabled(false);
    gui.stop.setEnabled(true);
    gui.reset.setEnabled(false);
    gui.quickpick.setSelected(false);
    gui.personal.setEnabled(false);

}

void stopPlaying() {
    gui.play.setEnabled(true);
    gui.stop.setEnabled(false);
    gui.reset.setEnabled(true);
    gui.quickpick.setSelected(true);
    gui.personal.setEnabled(true);
    playing = null;

}

void clearAllFields() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        gui.winners[i].setText(null);
        gui.numbers[i].setText(null);
    }

    gui.got3.setText("0");
    gui.got4.setText("0");
    gui.got4.setText("0");
    gui.got5.setText("0");
    gui.got6.setText("0");

    gui.years = null;
    gui.drawings = null;


}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
    Object item = event.getItem();
    if (item == gui.quickpick) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            int pick;
            do {
                pick = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 + 1);

            } while (numberGone(pick, gui.numbers, i));
            gui.numbers[i].setText("" + pick);
        }
    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            gui.numbers[i].setText(null);
        }
    }

}

void addOneToField(JTextField field) {
    int num = Integer.parseInt("0" + field.getText());
    num++;
    field.setText("" + num);
}

boolean numberGone(int nums, JTextField[] pastNums, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(pastNums[i].getText()) == nums) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

boolean matchedOne(JTextField win, JTextField[] allpicks) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        String winText = win.getText();
        if (winText.equals(allpicks[i].getText())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Thread thisThread = new Thread();
    while (playing == thisThread) {
        addOneToField(gui.drawings);
        int draw = Integer.parseInt(gui.drawings.getText());
        float numYears = (float) draw / 104;
        gui.years.setText("" + numYears);

        int matches = 0;
        for (int i = 6; i < 6; i++) {
            int ball;
            do {
                ball = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 + 1);
            } while (numberGone(ball, gui.winners, i));
            gui.winners[i].setText("" + ball);
            if (matchedOne(gui.winners[i], gui.numbers)) {
                matches++;
            }

        }
        switch (matches) {
            case 3:
                addOneToField(gui.got3);
                break;
            case 4:
                addOneToField(gui.got4);
                break;
            case 5:
                addOneToField(gui.got5);
                break;
            case 6:
                addOneToField(gui.got6);
                gui.stop.setEnabled(false);
                gui.play.setEnabled(true);
                playing = null;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

    }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know why your code is misbehaving, but I do know that 1) there's no reason for the LotteryEvent.java class to extend JFrame, 2) Your code does not obey Swing threading rules as you're changing Swing component state from within a background thread, something that should never be done. I'm not even sure why you have that background thread in your code in the first place. Can you explain the reason for its existence? Perhaps you mean to use a Swing Timer instead?

Comment: Swing is not thread safe, a better solution be to use a `SwingWorker` or event a Swing `Timer`.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: im going off a book called teach yourself java in 24 hours. We havent got to the threading part. This is what he recomended in his book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem is rather simply, the solution not so much...

When you call `startPlaying` you do...

```
playing = new Thread(this);
```

But when `run` is called, you then do this...

```
Thread thisThread = new Thread();
while (playing == thisThread) {
```

The problem is, `thisThread` and `playing` are never equal.

A better solution might be to use an `AtomicBoolean` as a running state flag and check that instead...however...

Swing is not thread safe and you are trying to update the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

A better solution would be to actually use a Swing `Timer`, this will allow you to setup a repeated call back at a regular delay which will be notified within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

The other benefit is, Swing `Timer` has a `stop` method of it's own...

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

As has already been pointed out, there is no need for `LotteryEvent` to extend from `JFrame`, in fact, I'd argue that it shouldn't even implement `ActionListener` or `ItemListener`, but that's me

**Updated with example**

Also, this `for (int i = 6; i < 6; i++) {` is wrong...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class LotteryInterface extends JPanel {

    LotteryEvent hello = new LotteryEvent(this);

    //set up row 1 
    JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
    ButtonGroup option = new ButtonGroup();
    JCheckBox quickpick = new JCheckBox("Quick Pick", false);
    JCheckBox personal = new JCheckBox("Personal", true);
    //set up row 2 
    JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
    JLabel numbersLabel = new JLabel("Your Picks", JLabel.RIGHT);
    JTextField[] numbers = new JTextField[6];
    JLabel winnersLabel = new JLabel("Winners", JLabel.RIGHT);
    JTextField[] winners = new JTextField[6];
    //set up row 3
    JPanel row3 = new JPanel();
    JButton play = new JButton("Play");
    JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
    //set up row 4
    JPanel row4 = new JPanel();
    JLabel got3label = new JLabel("3 of 6", JLabel.RIGHT);
    JTextField got3 = new JTextField("0");
    JLabel got4Label = new JLabel("4 of 6", JLabel.RIGHT);
    JTextField got4 = new JTextField("0");
    JLabel got5label = new JLabel("5 of 6", JLabel.RIGHT);
    JTextField got5 = new JTextField("0");
    JLabel got6label = new JLabel("6 of 6", JLabel.RIGHT);
    JTextField got6 = new JTextField("0", 10);
    JLabel drawingsLabel = new JLabel("Drawings", JLabel.RIGHT);
    JTextField drawings = new JTextField();
    JLabel yearsLabel = new JLabel("Years", JLabel.RIGHT);
    JTextField years = new JTextField();

    public LotteryInterface() {
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10);
        setLayout(layout);

        ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                Object item = e.getItem();
                if (item == quickpick) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                        int pick;
                        do {
                            pick = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 + 1);

                        } while (numberGone(pick, numbers, i));
                        numbers[i].setText("" + pick);
                    }
                } else {

                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                        numbers[i].setText(null);
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        personal.addItemListener(itemListener);
        quickpick.addItemListener(itemListener);
        play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                hello.start();
            }
        });
        stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                hello.stop();
            }
        });
        reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                hello.stop();
                clearAllFields();
            }
        });

        FlowLayout layout1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10);
        option.add(quickpick);
        option.add(personal);
        row1.setLayout(layout1);
        row1.add(quickpick);
        row1.add(personal);
        add(row1);

        GridLayout layout2 = new GridLayout(2, 7, 10, 10);
        row2.setLayout(layout2);
        row2.add(numbersLabel);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            numbers[i] = new JTextField();
            row2.add(numbers[i]);
        }
        row2.add(winnersLabel);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            winners[i] = new JTextField();
            winners[i].setEditable(false);
            row2.add(winners[i]);
        }
        add(row2);

        FlowLayout layout3 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10);
        row3.setLayout(layout3);
        row3.add(stop);
        row3.add(play);
        row3.add(reset);
        add(row3);

        GridLayout layout4 = new GridLayout(2, 3, 20, 10);
        row4.setLayout(layout4);
        row4.add(got3label);
        got3.setEditable(false);
        row4.add(got3);
        row4.add(got4Label);
        got4.setEditable(false);
        row4.add(got4);
        row4.add(got5label);
        got5.setEditable(false);
        row4.add(got5);
        row4.add(got6label);
        got6.setEditable(false);
        row4.add(got6);
        row4.add(drawingsLabel);
        drawings.setEditable(false);
        row4.add(drawings);
        row4.add(yearsLabel);
        years.setEditable(false);
        row4.add(years);
        add(row4);

    }

    void clearAllFields() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            winners[i].setText(null);
            numbers[i].setText(null);
        }

        got3.setText("0");
        got4.setText("0");
        got4.setText("0");
        got5.setText("0");
        got6.setText("0");

        years = null;
        drawings = null;

    }

    boolean numberGone(int nums, JTextField[] pastNums, int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(pastNums[i].getText()) == nums) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new LotteryInterface());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class LotteryEvent {

        LotteryInterface gui;
        private Timer timer;

        public LotteryEvent(LotteryInterface in) {
            gui = in;
            timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    addOneToField(gui.drawings);
                    int draw = Integer.parseInt(gui.drawings.getText());
                    float numYears = (float) draw / 104;
                    gui.years.setText("" + numYears);

                    int matches = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                        int ball;
                        do {
                            ball = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 + 1);
                        } while (numberGone(ball, gui.winners, i));
                        gui.winners[i].setText("" + ball);
                        if (matchedOne(gui.winners[i], gui.numbers)) {
                            matches++;
                        }

                    }
                    switch (matches) {
                        case 3:
                            addOneToField(gui.got3);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            addOneToField(gui.got4);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            addOneToField(gui.got5);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            addOneToField(gui.got6);
                            gui.stop.setEnabled(false);
                            gui.play.setEnabled(true);
                            stop();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void stop() {
            timer.stop();
        }

        public void start() {
            timer.start();
        }

        void addOneToField(JTextField field) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt("0" + field.getText());
            num++;
            field.setText("" + num);
        }

        boolean matchedOne(JTextField win, JTextField[] allpicks) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                String winText = win.getText();
                if (winText.equals(allpicks[i].getText())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem

```
Thread thisThread = new Thread();
```

needed to be changed to

```
Thread thisThread = thread.currentThread();
```

Comment: So why exactly is this all bad?